# How to insert Gazebo plugin in an existing World Model?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, from the tutorials I learned how to make a Gazebo Plugin. I successfully made the plugin and got the '.so' file.

I have an existing ROS package, which has world files and a lib folder with many '.so' files. How do I add my plugin to this existing package?
I tried simple copying 'my_model.so' file in lib folder and modifying the respective `<plugin ... filename="my_model.so".. >` command.

But it did not seems to work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249681/how-to-insert-gazebo-plugin-in-an-existing-world-model?/) by [kapoor_amita](https://answers.ros.org/users/28643/kapoor_amita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-12-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If done correctly, [here](https://github.com/pal-robotics/gazebo_ros_link_attacher/blob/master/worlds/test_attacher.world) is an example I have used before.

You can then include empty_world.launch in a launch file and overwrite the world name like [this](https://github.com/pal-robotics/gazebo_ros_link_attacher/blob/master/launch/test_attacher.launch).

---

Originally posted by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) with karma: 592 on 2016-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0